# preg_replace with associative array

Tags: php

I have some like this:

```
$fabrics = array (
        'B' => 'BAWEŁNA',
        'P' => 'POLIESTER',
        'S' => 'SPANDEX',
        'E' => 'ELASTAN',
        'PO' => 'POLIAMID',
        'EL' => 'ELASTAN',
        'A' => 'AKRYL',
        'AN' => 'ANGORA',
        'NY' => 'NYLON',
        'W' => 'WEŁNA',
        'WO' => 'WEŁNA OWCZA',
        'POL' => 'POLIWINYL',
        'PVC' => 'PCV',
        'SZJ' => 'SZTUCZNY JEDWAB',
        'SK' => 'SKÓRA NATURALNA',
        'POP' => 'POLIPROPYLEN' 
);

$textiles = array( 'B 100%', 'B 80%, P 20%', 'NY 70%, EL 30%', 'B 75%, S 20%', 'SZJ 80%, E 20%');
// rand textilies
$textile = $textiles[array_rand($textiles)];

echo $textile.'</br>';
echo preg_replace(array_keys($fabrics), $fabrics, $textile);
```

And i want use preg_replace to change a key in full name. But it's not work corectly.:/ Can you help?

Comment: Because you're not using a regular expression.  Just use `echo str_replace(array_keys($fabrics), $fabrics, $textile);`

Comment: So if i want use regular expression in this example what i must to do?

Comment: You don't. Why?  Just use `str_replace()` or Barmar's great answer.

Comment: Because i knew this solution with strtr and i interesting how i can do with preg_replace without change in array

Answer (score 2):

Your array keys aren't regular expressions, they're just ordinary strings. You can use [`strtr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) for this.

```
echo strtr($textile, $fabrics);
```

With two arguments, the second argument is an associative array of `from => to`.

Comment: Damn, I always forget about this one.

Comment: The perfect one ! Didn't know about this function. Thanks for the share.